# Absolute positioning of a <div>

Tags: css

In the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avillalain/xtm9D/), I am trying to find out why the div where the checkbox is placed is bigger than the content itself (which is only the image of an empty checkbox). I am trying to accomplish the same as seen on the fiddler but without the overlapping of the white background over the border of the underlying .
I think the problem is related to this css style:

```
.selectable-content label:after {
    background: white;
    color: #9fc5e8;
    content:"\f096";
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: I didn't understood your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to play with some of the bottom values in your media queries, but your white background was due to default `line-height` on the label.

http://jsfiddle.net/xtm9D/11/

Added:

```
.selectable-content > label {
    padding-top: -5px;
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height:26px;
}
```

Messed around with your media queries as well.

Comment: Np! Glad we got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

The element created by `:after` contains the character, but also has a white background. As this element later in the DOM and positioned at the bottom-right of its parent, it will overlap the background.

This could be fixed by creating a translucent picture of the actual image, and removing the white color from the CSS.

Comment: I added the white background because the character is transparent by itself. I thought that the size of the div would be the size of the character itself but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the line-height. When I add the line

```
line-height: 31px
```

to

```
.selectable-content > label {...
```

the problem is resolved. I initially set `line-height: 32px`, but there was still a pixel of white. You are going to need to find a consistent way to position the element and set the line-height in relation to the checkmark character to resolve the overflow.